# Parameter Decorators in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, decorator

I have used decorator on React Native with typescript. I can use decorator everywhere but I can't use as parameter decorator. For example

```
@Client('API_LINK')
export class Service {

   @Request<any>('/profile/:id', MethodEnums.GET)
   getDeneme(@UrlParam('id') id: number): any {
       return null
   }
}
```

`@Client` and `@Request` work but `@UrlParam` throws an error

> Unhandled JS Exception: Invalid Character '@' no stack